# How to generate stub in android?

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me which tool is used to generate Stub in Android and is it possible to use JAX-RPC concept to call the web service in android.If is it possible please provide me some code with example.
regards,
s.kumaran

Answer (score 1):

After defining your interface as `<interface>.aidl` in eclipse go to project->build project.

It will automatically generates `<interface>.java` file. This will contains stub class.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me which tool is used to generate Stub in Android

You seem to treat "Stub" as if it is a magic word. Given a few minutes, I can probably come up with a dozen or two different types of "stub".

The only "Stub" that Android handles natively is an [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html) stub.

> is it possible to use JAX-RPC concept to call the web service in android

Only if you supply your own Android-compliant JAX-RPC library.

Answer (score 0):

If you use eclipse, it takes care of generating stubs. In my case, eclipse did not generate it automatically. I cleaned the project and built again.