# How are .java files in android_stubs_current_intermediates directory generated?

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

The Android build process generates(?) Java stubs for each of the classes in the android.jar, and stores them in the following directory:

`./out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_stubs_current_intermediates/src/`

For example, the subdirectory `java/lang/` of the above directory contains .java files corresponding to java.lang.* classes, and the subdirectory `android/app/' contains .java files corresponding to android.app.* classes. These .java files dont contain actual code, but just signatures with dummy bodies.

I am assuming that those .java files are generated from the actual source code using a tool. My question is, which is this tool, and is it usable outside of the Android build process?

I want to use that tool to generate stubs for non-Android Java classes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264530/how-to-generate-stub-in-android?rq=1 may have some answers, not sure though I don't know much about it.

Comment: My question is different. By stubs, I specifically mean the .java files that are produced in the aforementioned directory as part of the Android's build process.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "stubs" here is the framework API stub generated by running javadoc tool.

> In most cases, when we talk about stub file in Android, we mean the java file generated by aidl tool. For example see [How to generate stub in android? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264530/how-to-generate-stub-in-android)

In particular, the Android build system contains a makefile called `droiddoc.mk` that can be used to generate documentation, java API stubs and API xml files, which actually calls javadoc.
`droiddoc.mk` is under `build/core`. In `build/core/config.mk` there is a variable named `BUILD_DROIDDOC` to make it easier to include the `droiddoc.mk`.

Look at the `droiddoc.mk`, it calls javadoc:

```
javadoc \
            \@$(PRIVATE_SRC_LIST_FILE) \
            -J-Xmx1280m \
            $(PRIVATE_PROFILING_OPTIONS) \
            -quiet \
            -doclet com.google.doclava.Doclava \
            -docletpath $(PRIVATE_DOCLETPATH) \
            -templatedir $(PRIVATE_CUSTOM_TEMPLATE_DIR) \
            $(PRIVATE_DROIDDOC_HTML_DIR) \
            $(addprefix -bootclasspath ,$(PRIVATE_BOOTCLASSPATH)) \
            $(addprefix -classpath ,$(PRIVATE_CLASSPATH)) \
            -sourcepath $(PRIVATE_SOURCE_PATH)$(addprefix :,$(PRIVATE_CLASSPATH)) \
            -d $(PRIVATE_OUT_DIR) \
            $(PRIVATE_CURRENT_BUILD) $(PRIVATE_CURRENT_TIME) \
            $(PRIVATE_DROIDDOC_OPTIONS) \
    && touch -f $@
```

There is nothing about the stub right? Don't worry, notice that there is a `PRIVATE_DROIDDOC_OPTIONS` variable, and

```
PRIVATE_DROIDDOC_OPTIONS := $(LOCAL_DROIDDOC_OPTIONS)
```

Many Android.mk files in AOSP, for example the `framework/base/Android.mk`, contain the `include $(BUILD_DROIDDOC)` to generate docs. In `framework/base/Android.mk`, there is a piece of code:

```
LOCAL_DROIDDOC_OPTIONS:=\
                $(framework_docs_LOCAL_DROIDDOC_OPTIONS) \
                -stubs $(TARGET_OUT_COMMON_INTERMEDIATES)/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_stubs_current_intermediates/src \
                -api $(INTERNAL_PLATFORM_API_FILE) \
                -nodocs

LOCAL_DROIDDOC_CUSTOM_TEMPLATE_DIR:=build/tools/droiddoc/templates-sdk

LOCAL_UNINSTALLABLE_MODULE := true

include $(BUILD_DROIDDOC)
```

The `LOCAL_DROIDDOC_OPTIONS` contains a `-stubs` option. And it will finally put into the javadoc command used by droiddoc.mk.

However, we may notice that the javadoc doesn't contain any option like `-stubs`. The key is that you can customize the content and format of the Javadoc tool's output by using doclets. The Javadoc tool has a default "built-in" doclet, called the standard doclet, that generates HTML-formatted API documentation. You can modify or subclass the standard doclet, or write your own doclet to generate HTML, XML, MIF, RTF or whatever output format you'd like.

We can use the `-doclet` option to specify our customized doclet. And the javadoc command in droiddoc.mk use the `-doclet com.google.doclava.Doclava`. That doclet receives the `-stubs` option.

Look at the Doclava implementation under `external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/Doclava.java`

```
  else if (a[0].equals("-stubs")) {
    stubsDir = a[1];
  } else if (a[0].equals("-stubpackages")) {
    stubPackages = new HashSet<String>();
    for (String pkg : a[1].split(":")) {
      stubPackages.add(pkg);
    }
  }
```

It receives the -stubs option. And here is how it process the stubsDir.

```
// Stubs
if (stubsDir != null || apiFile != null || proguardFile != null) {
  Stubs.writeStubsAndApi(stubsDir, apiFile, proguardFile, stubPackages);
}
```

And trace the implementation of the `Stubs.writeStubsAndApi`, you can see why the content in the stub files are like that.

You can even write your own java files and generate your stubs like what the test cases under `build/tools/droiddoc/test`.

Comment: Thanks for answering! AIDL files have a [different purpose](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html). I dont think that stubs are generated from the AIDL files. For example, notice that the above list does not include AIDL files for classes like Activity, Service or Java's standard library classes like java.lang.Object (all of which appear in android.jar).

Comment: Then what exactly are you asking? The stub file doesn't mean the XXX.jar or java.lang.Object or any activity service file in general. In most cases, when we talk about stub file in Android, we mean the java file generated by aidl tool. Are you asking about how android.jar is generated?

Comment: Yes (in a way). It seems that android.jar is compiled from .java files that are in the directory out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_stubs_current_intermediates/src/. I am asking how those .java files are generated.

Comment: Ok, I now get what you mean, I will update this answer soon. @SaswatAnand

Comment: I've updated the answer, and hope this is what you need. @SaswatAnand

Comment: @StarPinkER , here I add some java static libraries which is needed by framework-base. And in this static library, there are some classes which import framework-base hide class. So in droiddoc task, it always failed because of linking Parameter of hidden type android.app.IInstrumentationWatcher in android.app.ActivityThread.ApplicationThread.bindApplication(). Is there any solution for this problem?