# Generate stubs in Android Framework

Tags: android, makefile, frameworks

According to this post : [How are .java files in android_stubs_current_intermediates directory generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074794/how-are-java-files-in-android-stubs-current-intermediates-directory-generated)

I tried to generate the stubs present in the `test/generics/src` folder and I just changed the two of the last lines :

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=$(call all-java-files-under,src)

LOCAL_MODULE:=test_stubs
LOCAL_DROIDDOC_OPTIONS:=\
        -stubs $(OUT_DIR)/__test_stubs__

LOCAL_DROIDDOC_CUSTOM_TEMPLATE_DIR:=build/tools/droiddoc/templates-sdk
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := JAVA_LIBRARIES

include $(BUILD_DROIDDOC)
```

But when I do the `mm` in the current folder of the makefile nothing happends (and no generation of the `__test_stubs__` folder) and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to find the answer :

- Go to the folder where the `Android.mk` is
- do `mm <local_module_name>-docs`. In this context : `mm test_stubs-docs`

Hope it helps